# error to install lightdm because of plymouth

Tags: 13.04, lightdm, dependencies, plymouth

When I use this command `sudo apt-get update` , the output is as follows:

```
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner i386 Packages
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Reading package lists...
```

and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. I have this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  lightdm
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Then I ran this command `sudo apt-cache policy lightdm`, I have this output:

```
lightdm:
  Installed: 1.6.0-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.6.0-0ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
     1.6.0-0ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.6.0-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.3-0ubuntu2.3 0
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Then, I ran this command: `apt-cache policy plymouth` , and I got this output:

```
plymouth:
  Installed: 0.8.8-0ubuntu6
  Candidate: 0.8.8-0ubuntu6
  Version table:
 *** 0.8.8-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.8.2-2ubuntu31.1 0
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     0.8.2-2ubuntu30 0
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks,my system is ubuntu13.04, 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of `plymouth` in `raring/main` is `0.8.8-0ubuntu6.2`, whereas in your cached APT lists it is `0.8.8-0ubuntu6`. There is a small possibility that this is caused by a lagging mirror, in which case it will fix itself within a day.

However, it won't harm to force APT to obtain the latest package lists. Remove the cached APT lists from your system and run `apt-get update` to refresh them:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Before you do this, please note that you are using both the 12.04 (precise) and 13.04 (raring) archives. Unless you have a specific reason for doing so, I'd suggest removing the 12.04 package sources. Also, you seem to be using PPA's. Disable any that you don't need anymore, as these may also disturb the dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

should upgrade the kept back package.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: @tqjustc Please run the commands shown in this answer again and report any errors or warnings (do not comment, add them to your question). Also please add the output of `apt-cache policy lightdm` and `apt-cache policy plymouth` to your question. Please do not copy screen shots, rather copy and paste the actual output. Format it as a blockquote using the buttons in the editor.